# How to specify class attribute type in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like create an attribute `friends` of type array and an attribute `skills` of type Skill (Skill will be a class)

And my attributes can't be of another type but my attribute `friends` can be null!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You didn't undestand ?

Comment: What you wanna do is perfectly clear but you do not give neither the code nor what is blocking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for method arguments, but *not* for fields.

Consider making fields `private` and define getters/setters:

```
private $friends; // there's no possibility to define types here. 
private $skill;

public function setFriends(array $friends = null) {
    $this->friends = $friends;
}

public function setSkill(Skill $skill) {
    $this->skill = $skill;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer !! :D